# Custom linear transformation in keras

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I want to build a customized layer in keras to do a linear transformation on the output of last layer.
For example, I got an output X from last layer, my new layer will output X.dot(W)+b.

The shape of W is `(49,10)`, and the shape of X should be `(64,49)`, the shape of b is (10,)

However, the shape of X is `(?, 7, 7, 64)`, when I am trying to reshape it, it becomes `shape=(64, ?)`. What is the meaning of question mark? Could you tell me a proper way to do linear transformation on the output of last layer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question mark generally represents the batch size, which has no effect on the model architecture.

You should be able to reshape your `X` with `keras.layers.Reshape((64,49))(X)`.

You can wrap arbitrary tensorflow operations such as `tf.matmul` in a [Lambda](https://keras.io/layers/core/#lambda) layer to include custom layers in your Keras model. Minimal working example that does the trick:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.layers import Dense, Lambda, Input
from keras.models import Model

W = tf.random_normal(shape=(128,20))
b = tf.random_normal(shape=(20,))

inp = Input(shape=(10,))
x = Dense(128)(inp)
y = Lambda(lambda x: tf.matmul(x, W) + b)(x)
model = Model(inp, y)
```

Finally: refer to the [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/guides/making_new_layers_and_models_via_subclassing/) on how to write custom layers with trainable weights.

Comment: How can the weights of the linear transformation W be learned with the model?

Comment: You'd need to write a custom layer. The first example here basically covers it: https://keras.io/guides/making_new_layers_and_models_via_subclassing/