# Using custom tensorflow ops in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am having a script in tensorflow which contains the custom tensorflow ops. I want to port the code to keras and I am not sure how to call the custom ops within keras code.

I want to use tensorflow within keras, so the tutorial I found so far is describing the opposite to what I want: https://blog.keras.io/keras-as-a-simplified-interface-to-tensorflow-tutorial.html.

I also read about Lambda layers that can wrap arbitrary custom function, yet I did not see an example for tf.ops.

If you could provide code snippet with a simplest example how to do that I would be very grateful. For example assuming the tf.ops as:

```
outC = my_custom_op(inA, inB)
```

---EDIT:
Similar problem has been described in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45067108/tensorflow-op-in-keras-model) - essentially calling [this](https://github.com/zplizzi/tensorflow-fast-rcnn/tree/master/tensorflow/core/user_ops) custom op in keras, however I cannot grasp the solution how to apply it on another example that I want, for instance [this](https://github.com/charlesq34/pointnet2/tree/master/tf_ops/sampling) one. This custom tf op is first compiled (for gpu) and then so far used within tensorflow as [here](https://github.com/charlesq34/pointnet2/blob/master/utils/pointnet_util.py), see @ line 40. It is clear for me how to use a custom (lambda) function wrapped in Lambda layer, what I would like to understand is how to use the compiled custom ops, if I use keras.

Comment: Do you mean a custom layer?

Comment: In order to use TensorFlow within Keras you can do `from keras import backend as K` where `K` corresponds to TensrFlow. For example `K.nn.relu` is equivalent to `tf.nn.relu` etc

Comment: @Colonder, thanks for your help. Please read the updated description. I am not sure whether this precompiled custom op can/should be made into custom layer. If yes, that is the concept I want to understand on a simple example, I provided exemplary github repos above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can wrap arbitrary tensorflow functions in a keras `Lambda` layer and add them to your model. Minimal working example [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51523305/custom-linear-transformation-in-keras/51523393#51523393):

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.layers import Dense, Lambda, Input
from keras.models import Model

W = tf.random_normal(shape=(128,20))
b = tf.random_normal(shape=(20,))

inp = Input(shape=(10,))
x = Dense(128)(inp)
# Custom linear transformation
y = Lambda(lambda x: tf.matmul(x, W) + b, name='custom_layer')(x) 
model = Model(inp, y)
```

Comment: I think it would be better to stick with Keras' ideology and do `from keras import backend as K` instead of `import tensorflow as tf`

Comment: Are all tensorflow functions avaible in the keras backend? `K.matmul` gives me an error for instance.

Comment: Yes, they are but they don't have the same names. `tf.matmul` is equivalent to `K.dot`

Comment: But yeah, at the end of the day it doesn't really matter

Comment: I'll leave my answer as is because the question is specifically about using custom tensorflow inside Keras. K.nn.relu seems also not available btw.

Comment: No, all tensorflow functions are not available in keras backend. And many are changed, use different inputs, have limited functionality. I tried for a while to use only K functions, but that was simply too limiting. -- The only problem you will have for using `tf` instead of `K` is losing the possibility of migrating your code to other backends.

Comment: @sdcbr thank you, please read my last edit where I specified on an example what exactly is not clear for me. I refer to a line of code written in tensorflow that calls the function from the compiled op - how would it look like with Lambda?

Comment: The example you provide is quite complex. You can maybe look into the new `autograph.convert()` decorator, use it to define your op and wrap that in a `Lambda` layer? See https://medium.com/tensorflow/autograph-converts-python-into-tensorflow-graphs-b2a871f87ec7?linkId=54396538